# Eclipse CDT, cstdint and cinttypes types headers not found

Tags: c++, eclipse, header, inclusion

I have a very simple eclipse C++ project with the following three files:

header.h

```
#ifndef HEADER_H_
#define HEADER_H_

#include <cstdint>
#include <cinttypes>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <cassert>

void func1();


#endif
```

src.cc

```
#include "header.h"

void func1() {

}
```

main.cc

```
#include "header.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
   return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile the project, the compilation goes but it says:

```
make all
Building file: ../main.cc
Invoking: Cross G++ Compiler
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"main.d" -MT"main.d" -o "main.o" "../main.cc"
In file included from ../main.cc:8:
../header.h:11:19: warning: cstdint: No such file or directory
../header.h:12:21: warning: cinttypes: No such file or directory
Finished building: ../main.cc

Building file: ../src.cc
Invoking: Cross G++ Compiler
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"src.d" -MT"src.d" -o "src.o" "../src.cc"
In file included from ../src.cc:8:
../header.h:11:19: warning: cstdint: No such file or directory
../header.h:12:21: warning: cinttypes: No such file or directory
Finished building: ../src.cc

Building target: Test
Invoking: Cross G++ Linker
g++  -o "Test"  ./main.o ./src.o
Finished building target: Test
```

Namely it can't find the headers cstdint and cinttypes, is there something I can check to understand why they're not found?

Answer (score 0):

The `cstdint` header was introduced in C++11, which GCC does not default to.  In your project properties, select `Settings` under `C/C++ Build`.  On the `Tool Settings` tab, under `GCC C++ Compiler`, select `Dialect`.  Set the `Language standard` setting to `ISO C++ 11` (or newer if you prefer).  Recompile.

[image]